# AngularJS : Scope access between directives and transcluded directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I built a small demo of a modular form, consisting of individual input directive in it.
It also has a preview of the form values, bound to the same controller and scope.

The input directives that cause the issue are the inputs that are transcluded inside the form:

```
<mailer-form>
  <mailer-input form="mail" model="email">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="mail.email">
  </mailer-input>
</mailer-form>

<mailer-preview></mailer-preview>
```

You can take a look at it here:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/0FuzfOFFDN5XcNyZcpBv
```

The problem is that ng-models in the form's template update the parent scope,
while the transcluded inputs don't. That's why the first email input doesnt work
and the rest do.

How can I make the transcluded directives bind both ways?

Thanks!

Comment: so the problem is you're seeing the email input twice? Am I understanding that right? That is all I am seeing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-transclude directive always create a new child scope for the transcluded content.

There is a request here (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489) to not create a new scope but it hasn't implemented yet.

If you want the transcluded content to have the same scope as the container, you can use the `transcludeFn` in link() like the below snippet instead of ng-transclude.

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, controllers, transcludeFn){
  transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
    element.find('.transclude-here').append(nodes);
  })
}
```

and replace those

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

with

```
<div class="transclude-here"></div>
```

For the full example, see http://plnkr.co/edit/WYCOxC9xBIOTUWPs2iAq?p=preview

**Edit:** if you want this behavior in multiple places, you can write your own customized version of ng-transclude like this:

```
app.directive('myTransclude', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
        element.empty();
        element.append(nodes);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and in html template:

```
 <div my-transclude></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the scope situation with transclusion runTarm. The transclusion directive looks like a solid way to build this as a reusable component.